# How can I calculate the angle between my phone and another lat long?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, gyroscope

I am working on a application that points at a place. I have the latitude and longtitude of my phone and the place I want to point at. And I have never worked with a gyroscope. I hope to create a function like this:

```
getAngle(lat1, lng1,lat2.lng2) {

return angle;
}
```

Maby someone worked with this before?

I tried to get the dms from both parties but I think it could work with longtitude and latitude.
Im using these functions to convert my long and latitude to dms:

```
toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(coordinate) {
  var absolute = Math.abs(coordinate);
  var degrees = Math.floor(absolute);
  var minutesNotTruncated = (absolute - degrees) * 60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(minutesNotTruncated);
  var seconds = Math.floor((minutesNotTruncated - minutes) * 60);

  return degrees + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
}

convertDMS(lat, lng) {
  var latitude = this.toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat);
  var latitudeCardinal = lat >= 0 ? "N" : "S";

  var longitude = this.toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng);
  var longitudeCardinal = lng >= 0 ? "E" : "W";

  return latitude + " " + latitudeCardinal + "\n" + longitude + " " + longitudeCardinal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Haversine formula for finding angle. referring to [this](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```js
const getAngle = (lat1,lat2,long1,long2) => {
    
        const dLon = (long2 - long1);
    
        const y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
        const x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
                * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
    
        let brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
    
        brng = brng * 180 / Math.PI;
        brng = (brng + 360) % 360;
        brng = 360 - brng; // count degrees counter-clockwise - remove to make clockwise
    
        return brng;
    }
    
    console.log(getAngle(20,30,10,15))
    //161.54169612572116
```